# How to build a software package using CMake on an ARMHF (ARM32)?

Tags: github, cmake, raspberry-pi, arm64, armhf

I need to build a package from GitHub on my Raspberry Pi running Raspberry OS 32.

I have the following "setup_ubuntu_arm.sh" for ARM64 platform:

```bash
# run this script to install the packages needed to build and run AtomBeam
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install uuid-dev
sudo apt-get -y install make
sudo apt-get -y install pandoc
sudo apt-get -y install wget
sudo wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.26.0-rc5/cmake-3.26.0-rc5-linux-aarch64.tar.gz
tar -xzvf cmake-3.26.0-rc5-linux-aarch64.tar.gz
sudo cp -r cmake-3.26.0-rc5-linux-aarch64/bin /usr
sudo cp -r cmake-3.26.0-rc5-linux-aarch64/share /usr
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get -y install g++
sudo apt-get -y install rpm
sudo apt-get -y install doxygen
sudo apt-get -y install graphviz
sudo apt-get -y install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libghc-ncurses-dev
sudo apt-get -y install  papi-tools
sudo apt-get -y install papi-examples
sudo apt-get -y install graphviz
sudo apt-get -y install texlive texinfo
sudo apt-get -y install texlive-fonts-recommended
sudo apt-get -y install texlive-fonts-extra
sudo apt-get -y install texlive-latex-extra
sudo apt-get -y install zlib zlib-devel
sudo apt-get -y install zstd zstd-devel

sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev python3-venv python3-pip swig
```

My question is what do I need to change to be able to run this on ARM32 Raspberry Pi?

I tried to search for anything related to CMake for ARM32 on GitHub under:
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases but there are only aarch64 (ARM64) versions available.

Comment: Are you asking how to install CMake?

Comment: No, CMake is already installed. I'm asking how to use CMake to compile and link the existing software on a ARM32 architecture. i.e. what modifications I need to do to the above ARM64 Shell script to become useful for ARM32.

Comment: Try removing the four CMake-related lines then, if you have CMake already.